# Remove bone rotation influence on mesh?

Tags: bones

I only want my bone to affect the weight paint based only on it's location not it's rotation. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible, however you can limit the rotation of the bone, which will have the same effect. If the bone has children, simply duplicate it, and make all bones children of the duplicated bone, the original bone can then again be, rotation constrained.

Comment: What about taking the weight from this bone and transferring it to another? Is that possible? I haven't found a way to do that for bones within the same rig

Comment: Weights are just vertex groups, and they are "assigned" to bones by name. It is extremely basic (a good thing, I find). If you want the Vertex Group to follow BoneB, simply name it *BoneB*.